# SimSpark and RCSSServer report "undefined symbol: SDL_Init"

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to run SimSpark and RCSSServer when I type `$ rcsoccersim3d` in Terminal this happens:

```
(SimulationServer) SimControlNode 'AgentControl' registered
(AgentControl) Running in normal mode.
(spark.rb) sparkSetupInput
(spark.rb) using InputSystem 'InputSystemSDL'
/usr/local/bin/rcssserver3d: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/simspark/inputsdl.so: undefined symbol: SDL_WasInit
(MonitorServer) WARNING: SimulationServer not found.
rcssmonitor3d, 0.2
Koblenz University.
Copyright (C) 2004, The RoboCup Soccer Server Maintenance Group.

Type '--help' for further information

(spark.rb) sparkSetupRendering
(spark.rb) using OpenGLSystem 'OpenGLSystemSDL'
/usr/local/bin/rcssmonitor3d: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/simspark/openglsyssdl.so: undefined symbol: SDL_Init
kill: 65: No such process
```

I've installed most of the SDL packages but the problem isn't solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Comment these lines out in `simspark/plugin/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# It is problematic under Linux! Will cause segfaults on simspark exit.
#if (WIN32 OR APPLE)
   set(spark_libs kerosin oxygen salt zeitgeist)
#endif (WIN32 OR APPLE)
```

and build both SimSpark and RCSSServer3D again!

You can use the [Rubuntu Robocup Repository](http://robocup.allafiha.com) as a Ubuntu repository for installing the 2D & 3D soccer simulation server.

Answer (score 0):

I also found some discussion of this issue [here](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~xu/simspark.html):

After upgrading to ubuntu 11.10, the simspark can be compiled, but when run it, error appeared:

> ./simspark: symbol lookup error: …/lib/simspark/openglsyssdl.so: undefined symbol: SDLInit
>   ./simspark: symbol lookup error: …/lib/simspark/inputsdl.so: undefined symbol: SDLWasInit

The problem is that the `-lSDL` is not passed for some reason.  So for a quick fix, edit two files: `spark/plugin/openglsyssdl/CMakeList.txt` and `spark/plugin/inputsdl/CMakeList.txt`, add `SDL` in `target_link_libraries`.