# Error installing rcssserver3d : (MonitorServer) WARNING: SimulationServer not found. and (Light) ERROR: OpenGLServer not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm installing simspark on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have a slight the same error as in this

[SimSpark and RCSSServer report "undefined symbol: SDL_Init"](https://superuser.com/questions/350134/simspark-and-rcssserver-report-undefined-symbol-sdl-init)

```
(MonitorServer) WARNING: SimulationServer not found.
rcssserver3d (formerly simspark), a monolithic simulator 0.6.7
Copyright (C) 2004 Markus Rollmann, 
Universität Koblenz.
Copyright (C) 2004-2009, The RoboCup Soccer Server Maintenance Group.

Type '--help' for further information

(SimulationServer) SimControlNode 'AgentControl' registered
(AgentControl) Running in normal mode.
(spark.rb) sparkSetupInput
(spark.rb) using InputSystem 'InputSystemSDL'
(InputServer) Init InputSystemSDL
(InputServer) CreateDevice Keyboard
(InputServer) CreateDevice Mouse
(spark.rb) sparkSetupTimer
(spark.rb) using TimerSystem 'TimerSystemBoost'
(SimulationServer) SimControlNode 'InputControl' registered
(SimulationServer) TimerSystem 'TimerSystemBoost' registered
(bindings.rb) setting up bindings
(spark.rb) sparkEnableLog logTarget=:cerr logType=eError
(Light) ERROR: OpenGLServer not found
(Light) ERROR: OpenGLServer not found
```

SDL_Library is already in those two CMakeList.txt files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this output with the warnings and errors is normal. Let me know if you could proceed.

References:

https://www.cs.miami.edu/home/visser/csc752-files/simspark_install_1604.txt

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1084340)

Comment: I understand. My answer would be that I think it's normal output log. Since I don't know the reasons, and have been struggling myself to actually run this setup, I also linked this article I found. I'll edit it for clarity